# Why do applications sometimes crash the first time I open the Windows 8 file explorer?

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, crash

I have found that since upgrading to windows 8 (from windows 7) I occasionally get a problem with various applications crashing when I go to open a file from them using the file explorer.
After restarting the crashed application and browsing for a file again I invariably don't get the same problem. It seems to be the first time I do it, or something related to the time since I last did it.
Any ideas would be appreciated.
I am running things like Skydrive , Google drive, Dropbox in case that rings any bells.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "Crashing"?  What actually happens?  Anything related shown in the Event Logs?  Have you done disk checks? How about memory checks?

Comment: Which applications crash?

Comment: @magicandre1981 The applications that I remember seeing crash were Visual Studio 2012 Professional and Firefox but I beleive there was one or more other too. It's probably any application that uses the System File Explorer.

Comment: @techie007 - By crashing, I mean that the application hangs and I have to stop it in the task manager then restart it. I have not had any trouble when restarting the application or when subsequently browsing for a file immediately following the restart.

Comment: Have you upgraded via a clean install ? If you have any security product installed, you might try to disable it and reboot. It's also advisable to fully patch Windows including optional Windows Updates.

Comment: create crash dumps: http://pastebin.com/zKuJvw57 and share them

Comment: @AlanGee have you created the dumps?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I have just installed your dump thingy. Strangely though I don't seem to be getting the problem any longer. I am wondering if an update, windows or otherwise, has fixed the problem. I may have spoken too soon though and thanks anyway.

Comment: this .reg file fixes nothing. Look into Eventlog which updates where installed the last days.

Comment: @magicandre1981 - The only one that's within the right date-range is KB2889543. It relates to Flash Player so I don't think it's likely to have fixed my problem.

Comment: that's really strange.

Comment: This kind of sounds like a problem with an antivirus product.  In fact, it might not be a "problem", only slow response, as the AV product "comes up to speed" checking files and signatures.  If it hangs again, observe whether your disk light is flashing rapidly, and try waiting 5-10 minutes before bagging it.

Comment: Daniel - I use Microsoft Security Essentials, so I would expect a lot of people to have experienced similar problems if it was down to that. If it ever happens again, which is looking increasingly unlikely, I will try what you have suggested all the same.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something's wrong with your **Common Dialog DLL** (`comdlg32.dll`)?
Standart `Open/Save dialogs (windows)` belong to that dll, and a lot of programs use it.
If it's not working properly, then programs which use it can crash.

Try to find it (in internet or in windows installation disk,...) and replace that dll.

Comment: If it happens again I will try that but I haven't had the problem for about a week now and I don't know what's changed. I exited SkyDrive for a few days (I was a bit suspicious of it, just because it is networked up and is associated with the file explorer) and didn't get the problem, but since starting it again I also haven't had the problem for several days.

Answer (score 2):

Many users have the same problem on Windows 8. Try to use the following command in the cmd line to fix it:

- Open CMD as Administrator
- Type "sfc /scannow" (without quotes)
- Press Enter and wait between 10 - 30 minutes
- Now restart your pc and everything should work like expected.

Comment: "Many user have the same problem on windows 8" - Source?

Comment: There are many threads. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-winapps/windows-8-apps-crash-immediately-after-opening/f284fae3-2629-423b-8a2f-f02f0cdb5066 for example

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, and I will try it if I have further problems. However, the example link you referred to doesn't appear to have the same symptoms. My applications are fine until they call windows 8 file explorer and I open a file selected from it. I have recently tried disabling **SkyDrive** and have not experienced the problem since (about 3 days). Will Answer my own question if/when I find a definitive solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution but ironically, having lived with the problem for about 9 months, since posting this question I have not experienced the problem again. I can only assume that something, that I have so far been unable to pinpoint, has fixed the problem.

I will post a comment if it happens again.